# Alternative builds with Star Wars LEGO sets

Tags: building, star-wars

I currently own these LEGO Star Wars sets:

```
LEGO Star Wars X-Wing Starfighter 9493
LEGO Star Wars Millennium Falcon 7965
LEGO Star Wars Tie Fighter 9492
LEGO Star Wars Emperor Palpatine's Shuttle (8096)
LEGO Star Wars Slave 1 (8097)
LEGO Star Wars Anakin's & Sebulba's Podracers 7962
LEGO Star Wars AT-RT 75002
LEGO Star Wars 9496 Desert Skiff
LEGO Star Wars 9498 Saesee Tiin's Jedi Starfighter
LEGO Star Wars Rancor Pit 75005
LEGO Star Wars Luke's Landspeeder (8092)
LEGO Star Wars 9516 Jabba's Palace
LEGO Star Wars 9515 The Malevolence
Lego Star Wars Geonosian Starfighter 7959
```

I would like to know if there are alternative builds/sets I can make with some or all of them?

My goal is to build something else with what I have that is Star Wars related.

Thanks

Comment: You have a lot, and I like them all, you maybe can make some official sets out of your pieces. There is a page where it counts your inventory and pieces and tells you what officials sets you can build with that. I don't remember the link now but oddTodd has it, you may click on it. My answer, you can put the "Rancor Pit" and "Jaba's Palace" together, I mean, the palace above the "Rancor Pit" and you can make the famous scene when Luke falls into it. Good luck!!!

Comment: The brickbros on youtube also make great alternative builds, so you should check them out!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a website, http://rebrickable.com/, that lets you enter the sets you have, and it compares the inventories to other sets to determine which other official sets you can build with those pieces. It also includes unofficial MOCs that other builders have submitted, and it will substitute other part colors if you choose.

For example, just entering the first six sets on your list, it suggested a mid-sized (360 piece) TIE Interceptor MOC (http://rebrickable.com/mocs/anincompoop25/tie-interceptor) for which you already have all of the pieces.

Answer (score 3):

However, if you're looking for an official alternate/combiner build, then no. Star Wars isn't very big on combiner or alternate models, although the early, 1999 sets include inspirational photos. Over the years, Star Wars combiners/alternates have been released via LEGO Club or LEGO Build Together, but unfortunately none of your sets have an alternative/combiner build.

Comment: Build Together sounds nice ( https://www.wired.com/2012/05/lego-build-together/ ) but it seems to have been absorbed and lost into LEGO.com.