# Where can I find LEGO Digital Designer projects for Lego Technic MOCs?

Tags: ev3, building, technic, instructions

I have LEGO Technic pieces collected from multiple sets and would like to find projects on the web which I can view and build models step by step. Please advise sources where I can find these.

Answer (score 7):

Eurobricks forum has hundreds of official sets in LDD format here: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&#entry727293

Answer (score 2):

As suggested on [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2196/56) Rebrickable has a number of [MOCs based on Technic parts](http://rebrickable.com/search?q=Search...&theme=001&numpieces=0&maxpieces=1050&year=1975&yearto=2014&custom=1&pt=0&c=-1&sets=).

If you happen to know which sets you have, you can create an account, add your sets, and then filter those MOCs to just ones you can build.

However, not all of these are available as LDD projects, some are "photo sets".